# Flex box container overflows despite overflow:hidden and min-width: 0

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my flex box container to fit within the div
I've even set `min-width: 0` and `overflow: hidden` on everything in an act of desperation
but the flex box still isn't shrinking when the width is changed 
This is what it looks like when the width is changed
https://jsfiddle.net/o5c76hy2/25/
[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: relative;

}

#mainContainer {
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-width: auto;

}

.subContainer {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;

  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  min-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;


}

.item1 {
  margin-right: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 0;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head></head>

  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="mainContainer">
      <div class="subContainer">
        <span class="item1">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</span>
        <span class="item2" style="background-color: red;">bbb</span>
        <span class="item2" >c</span>
      </div>



    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

I've refered to other links like:
[Flex child is overflowing the parent container even after setting min-width:0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63601481/flex-child-is-overflowing-the-parent-container-even-after-setting-min-width0)
[Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

but I still can't seem to fix the problem, I'm pretty sure it's something obvious but I can't seem to pin point it, any help would be **severely** appreciated

Comment: The code here doesn’t match your fiddle, in there you have explicitly specified the width for the first item as 50% (and with different class names as well.) Not sure what exactly you _want_ to achieve here now, so please clarify that.

Comment: display:table is the culprit, remove it

Comment: @Temani Afif I removed the `display:table` but now it's causing a different issue like overflow and top whitespace
https://jsfiddle.net/0d5q8uma/2/

Answer (score 0):

In `#maincontainer` remove `display: table;`, and change `width: 50%;` to `width: calc(50% - 200px);`.
The end result should look like this:

```
#mainContainer {
  width: calc(50% - 200px);
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 100px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: could you add a snippet of the code so I can mark the answer as accepted?